# Web page with scripted iframes not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, iframe

I have a web page based on iframes, working on Android, Windows, and Linux. I can't test it on iPhone or MacOS, but people reported it doesn't work on iPhone.

The page is here: https://fractarchy.github.io/fractarchy-cms/

I'd appreciate if someone could help me working this out, or maybe to get me a report from Safari Developer Console, so I can draw my next moves.

I still have no data on what's happening on iPhone, I only know "it is not working" (probably not working on MacOS too).

On all other tested platforms, you should see this web page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a lot of clipping in rendering the contents, but it happens that Safari browser has a bug with clipping. The solution is to wrap clipped element within a <div> and to clip that parent <div> element.

Answer (score 1):

## TEST COMPLETED ON IPOD

So I tested your website on an iPod and it looks like the computer version. Their are a few issues including the text overflowing on the initial big bubble, the text not appearing on the smaller bubbles and the dragging function not working. I believe that on iPhones, if you hold a spot on your screen for a few seconds, it zooms in. I think that's what's happening here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a big time, it helps narrowing down the problem.